# Return an empty row with the necessary columns with NULL value

Tags: sqlite

I need to transform the following expression for SQLite, any idea how to do this?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT [ID] FROM [USERS] WHERE [ID]=1)
SELECT [ID], [NAME], [CITY] FROM [USERS] WHERE [ID]=1
ELSE   
SELECT NULL AS ID, NULL AS NAME, NULL AS CITY

UNION ALL

IF EXISTS (SELECT [ID] FROM [USERS] WHERE [ID]=2)
SELECT [ID], [NAME], [CITY] FROM [USERS] WHERE [ID]=2
ELSE   
SELECT NULL AS ID, NULL AS NAME, NULL AS CITY
```

In other words, I need to return an empty row with the necessary columns with NULL value, when the condition does not meet criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a virtual table of all the IDs you want, and then use a left [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) to get the matching `Users` record values or `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT Users.*
FROM (SELECT 1 AS ID
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2) AS IDList
LEFT JOIN Users ON IDList.ID = Users.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no `IF` statement, or any other control flow statement.

What you could do is to take the actual record (if it exists) *and* the `NULL` record together, and then take only the first one:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, Name, City FROM Users WHERE ID = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL
               LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, Name, City FROM Users WHERE ID = 2
               UNION ALL
               SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL
               LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your code.
Unfortunately, when one of the fields in the main table contains a blob field, SQLite does not handle its interpretation, and returns the random data for this field.

Comment: SQLite never changes the contents of blob values; there is likely to be a bug in your blob writing/reading code.

Comment: Yup! There is bug in SQLite explorer application. Sorry!